# Need help to explain seats at a cinema program made in java

Tags: java

Can someone please help me understand what is going on here? I find it hard to understand whats going on with these multidimentional arrays. If someone could explain me in detail what the program does. I'm supposed to find the first available seat at a movie theatre. The program will terminate by the first seat.

```
public class Cinema {




private boolean[][] seats = {{ true, true, false, false, false, true, true false},
                             { true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true},
                             { true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true}}



public void findAvailable() {

    boolean found = false;

    int row = 0;
    while (!found && row < seats.length) {
        int seat = 0;
        while (!found && seat < seats[row].length) {
          if (seats[row][seat]) {
            found = true;
            System.out.println("Row = " + row + " Seat = " + seat);
          }
          seat++;
        }
        row++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A movie theater is actually a good way to explain a 2 dimensional array.

```
boolean[][] seats = 
{{true, true, false, false, false, true, true false},
 {true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true},
 {true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true}  }
```

You could see every row in the array as a row of seats. Now you can use the first seat with `seats[0][0]`, or the second seat on the first row with `seats[0][1]`. In order to go through all seats on the **first** row, you can make a for loop:

```
for(x = 0; x < 8; x++){
    System.out.println("The boolean value of seat " + x + " on the first row is: " + seats[0][x]);
}
```

Now you can also search the **second** row (keep in mind that the index of an array always starts at 0) with `seats[1][x]`

Now, if you would like to loop through all possible seats, you would have to make two for loops: One to loop through the number of the seat and another one to loop through the rows:

```
for(y = 0; y < 3; y++){
    for(x = 0; x < 8; x++){
        System.out.println("The boolean value of seat " + x + " on row "+ y + " is: " + seats[y][x]);
    }
}
```

Note that you cannot loop further than the size of the array (3 rows and 8 seats). That is why you are using the `.length` attribute to determine the size.

Now the only thing to do is to find the first seat that is available, so you loop through the array once again and when the boolean value at that particular seat is `true`, you have to break out of both of the loops. That is why there is an extra boolean variable `found`, which is set to `true` when a seat is found and that causes the loop to not execute again (note the `!` in the while condition).

Answer (score 1):

First of all - **Multi dimensional arrays are nothing but arrays of arrays.**
To understand the code, please follow the comments at each line:

```
 public class Cinema {




   private boolean[][] seats = {{ true, true, false, false, false, true, true false},
                                 { true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true},
                                 { true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true}}



    public void findAvailable() {

        boolean found = false; // No available seats found be default

        int row = 0; // Number of the row set to 0 by default 
        while (!found && row < seats.length) { // While seat is not found AND row is not exceeding number of all rows 
            int seat = 0; // Number of seat set to 0 be default 
            while (!found && seat < seats[row].length) { // While seat is not found AND seat number is not exceeding the number of seats IN the row 
              if (seats[row][seat]) { // if seat at row number equals to true
                found = true; // set found to true
                System.out.println("Row = " + row + " Seat = " + seat);
              }
              seat++; // increment seat to next one
            }
            row++; // increment row to next one 
        }
    }
```

[A very good explanation of 2D arrays here](http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs231/lectures/chapter9/arrays2d.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite this algorithm as:

```
public void findAvailable() {

    boolean found = false;

    int row = 0;
    while (!found && row < seats.length) {
        int col= 0;
        while (!found && col< seats[row].length) {
          if (seats[row][col]) {
            found = true;
            System.out.println("Row = " + row + " Seat = " + seat);
          }
          col++;
        }
        row++;
    }
}
```

I hope it is self explanatory now. Keep on searching for a seat in every row starting from 0 and then same for column. So search start from `[0,0]` till `[n,n]` and when a seat is found we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by breaking down your code:

```
public class Cinema { ... }
```

So, here we're declaring a **new data type/data structure called** *Cinema*.

This data structure you're declaring, it has one private (you won't be able to access it from outside this **Cinema class**) attribute called **seats** which is of type **matrix of boolean** and a public method (which can be accessed from outside the Cinema class) called *findAvailable* which requires no parameters.

For clarification purposes, let's point out that any matrix is formed by a set of rows and every row has its set of columns. Also, the way we declare/access a matrix in Java is:

```
// Access; telling which columns and rows we want to access.
myMatrix[rowIndex][columnIndex];
// Creation; telling what sizes we want for our matrix.
DataType[][] variable = new DataType[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns];
```

So let's break down the code of those seats, shall we?

```
private boolean[][] seats = {{ true, true, false, false, false, true, true false},
                             { true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true},
                             { true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true}}
```

This is exactly the same as:

```
    private boolean[][] seats = {
               // This is the instantiation of one row, with 8 columns
               { true, true, false, false, false, true, true false},
               // Another row with another 8 more columns (and its values)                                     
               { true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true},
               // And another row.                      
               { true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true}
    };
```

So with some more spacing and indenting seems a bit clearer; basically, you're creating a matrix of booleans with 3 rows and 8 columns each row.

Moving on to the method, that method returns **void**, i.e. returns nothing.

In that method, you're performing a simple search on the matrix: you're visiting every single one of the cells looking for the first cell that contains a "true" value.

So let's go through your code by commenting it.

```
public void findAvailable() {
    /* You will use this auxiliar variable to tell or remember if you have found an available spot*/
    boolean found = false;
    /* This variable is your row indexer, an accumulator that you will use to remember which row to access and how many of them have you accessed at a given time*/
    int row = 0;
    /*this translates as follows:
    WHILE I HAVEN'T FOUND (the free spot) AND I HAVEN'T VISITED EACH ROW OF
    SEATS*/
    while (!found && row < seats.length) {
        /*The same thing, but now it's a column indexer*/
        int seat = 0;
        /*this translates as follows:
        WHILE I HAVEN'T FOUND (the free spot) AND I HAVEN'T VISITED EACH COLUMN
        OR/OF SEATS*/
        while (!found && seat < seats[row].length) {
          // Checking whether the seat at "row, seat" is available
          if (seats[row][seat]) {
            // If it is, remember it so we can stop looking any further
            found = true;
            // Notify that you've found an empty seat at "row, column"
            System.out.println("Row = " + row + " Seat = " + seat);
          }
          // Keep looking for seats in the same row
          seat++;
        }
        // If no luck on this row, let's move to another one
        row++;
    }

    // if we've reached this point...
    if(!found) System.out.println("There are no seats available this time...");
}
```