# I am trying to print a 2D array to a file

Tags: java, arrays, file, printing

I want to print 2D array to txt file on my desktop. It is important, that the output is formatted in way, that is in code, because it represents rows and seats.

Code:

```
package vaja15;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Vaja15 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        System.out.println("Vnesi velikost dvorane (vrste/sedezi):  ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r  = new Random();
        int vrst = sc.nextInt();
        int sedezev = sc.nextInt(); 
        int [][] dvorana  = new int [vrst][sedezev];
        File  file = new File ("C:/users/mr/desktop/dvorana.txt");


        for(int i = 0; i<dvorana.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println();
            for (int j = 0; j<dvorana.length; j++)
            {
                dvorana [i][j] = r.nextInt(3);  
                System.out.print(dvorana[i][j]);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file);
                out.println(dvorana[i][j]);
                out.close();
            }   
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189253/need-help-to-explain-seats-at-a-cinema-program-made-in-java/30189718#30189718)

Comment: Cool story, what's your question?

Comment: print a new line (println) ONLY when there is a new row and open the outputstream only once (as moffeltje suggests). It's really as simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not open and close a file in your loop: open a file before the loop, write your array, close the file. Otherwise it will overwrite the file over and over again.

Try this:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file);

for(int i = 0; i<vrst; i++)
{
    System.out.println();
    out.println();
    for (int j = 0; j<sedezev; j++)
    {
        dvorana [i][j] = r.nextInt(3);  
        System.out.print(dvorana[i][j]);          
        out.print(dvorana[i][j]);
    }   
}

out.close();
```

Comment: one more `out.println()` at the beginning of the outer loop and it works like a charm :)

Comment: @vefthym Thanks to both of you. This is exactly what i had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following idea:

```
try {
  File file = new File(path);
  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
  BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(writer);
  for (int[] array : matrix) {
    for (int item : array) {
       output.write(item);
       output.write(" ");
    }
    output.write("\n"); 
  }
  output.close();
} catch (IOException e) {

}
```